# Change Label text on button click in a different form

Tags: c#

I've 3 buttons, for this case call them button 1, 2 and 3. Then I have a different form in the same solution, with an label. What I want to have is when each button is pressed, the label.text needs to change on the other form.

Like for an example: When:
- Button 1 clicked: Label Text = 1
- Button 2 clicked: Label Text = 2
- Button 3 clicked: Label Text = 3

Comment: Are the forms already opened at the moment of the click?

Comment: Nope, but when you click on one of them, you should see the form 2 with changed label

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Application.OpenForms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.openforms%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) collection and add a simple method to each of your forms that requires the change

In the button click add

```
foreach (Form f in Application.OpenForms)
{
    if(f Is Form1)
        (f as Form1).ChangeLabel("NewText 1");
    else if (f is Form2)
        (f as Form2).ChangeLabel("NewText 2");
    else if (f is Form3))
        (f as Form3).ChangeLabel("NewText 3");
}
```

In each form that you want to change add (example for Form1)

```
.... other code inside your Form1,Form2,Form3 classes...
public void ChangeLabel(string newText)
{
    this.Label1.Text = newText;
}
.... other code inside your Form1,Form2,Form3 classes...
```

(Of course you need to change Form1,Form2,Form3 to the real names of the classes that implements your forms and the Label1 to the exact name of the label to change)

You can also make your labels public and use a syntax like

```
(f as Form1).Label1 = "New Text 1";
```

but I usally prefer to leave the controls hosted by the form not visible from external code.

**EDIT**

Looking at the comment below I understand that you have one forms with three buttons and one form with one label. And you want to change the label when you click on these buttons

Then the code would be the following (Set each button Click event to the same event handler using the designer. In this example I will call it ChangeLabel_Click

```
protected void ChangeLabel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = sender as Button;
    SecondFormType f = Application.OpenForms.OfType<SecondFormType>().FirstOrDefault();
    if(f != null)
    {
        if(btn.Name == "Button1")
           f.ChangeLabel("NewText 1");
        else if(btn.Name == "Button2")
           f.ChangeLabel("NewText 2");
        else if(btn.Name == "Button3")
           f.ChangeLabel("NewText 3");
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2**

The code above takes the first form of the SecondType so, if you have more than one instance opened of the form SecondType you need a loop to change every form instance

```
protected void ChangeLabel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = sender as Button;
    foreach(SecondFormType f in Application.OpenForms.OfType<SecondFormType>())
    {
        if(btn.Name == "Button1")
           f.ChangeLabel("NewText 1");
        else if(btn.Name == "Button2")
           f.ChangeLabel("NewText 2");
        else if(btn.Name == "Button3")
           f.ChangeLabel("NewText 3");
    }
}
```

Comment: VS says at that 2nt part: 
Invalid token ':' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
Don't know why, but 2x
And at that same part it says:
Member modifier 'public' must precede the member type and name

Comment: That was just an example on where you need to put the ChangeLabel method. It should be placed inside tha class of the forms that need to change the label. You already have the declaration of the Form class don't need to add again the declaration. I will remove it to avoid confusion

Comment: Aah okay, check! So do I have to change form1, 2 and 3 to the button names or the form names. Because there are just 2 forms. 1 with the 3 buttons and 1 with the lable that has to be changed.

Comment: I haven't understand your problem then. So let me try to understand. You have one forms with three buttons and one form with one label. Clicking on a button you want to change the label in the second form?

Comment: Yes that's it. But I've reviewed it, so 2 of the 3 buttons would give the same.. change :P

Comment: And 3 are now 4 buttons at one form at form 1!

Comment: Okay, I'n continueing with the project. I've One last error: Non-invocable member 'Application.OpenForms' cannot be used like a method

Comment: My mistake, remove the parenthesys after OpenForm. Answer updated

Comment: No errors! YAY XD but eh.. it doesn't work. I've tried it with the first if after the first one:

if (btn.Name == "B_5")
f.ChangeLabel("Cat");

Label in the second form doesn't change?

Comment: Do you have only one instance of the second form. The code above takes in consideration only the first instance of the second form. So if you have more than one only the first choosen will change, I could change that code to loop instead, so every second form will be updated.

Comment: I've just 1 form with one other label that has to be changed and only one other form where that has to be

Answer (score 0):

I would use some jQuery for this

```
$("#button1").on('click', function(){
   $("#label").empty().append("1");
});

$("#button2").on('click', function(){
   $("#label").empty().append("2");
});

$("#button3").on('click', function(){
   $("#label").empty().append("3");
});
```

and your label in html should be something like

```
<label id="label">Text</label>
```

probably missed something but given the lack of language i hope it gives an idea about what you want to do :)

Comment: I have feeling the OP is dealing with windows forms not web forms!

Comment: Uhu c# but doesn't matter!

Answer (score 0):

you can use a delegate event like this :

in your Form with your Buttons create a DelegateEvent

```
//Create a delegate
    public delegate void ButtonClickToOtherForm(object sender, EventArgs e);

    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        //Your own event based on created delegate
        public event ButtonClickToMainForm ButtonClickedToMainForm;

        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

       //This method will invoke your event
        private void OnButtonClickedToOtherForm(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ButtonClickedToOtherForm?.Invoke(this, e);
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //On button1_Click this will fire the event on the other form
            OnButtonClickedToMainForm(this, e);
        }
```

and in your Form with the Labels subscribe to that event

```
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //Subscribe to event from your other Form
            Form2.ButtonClickedToOtherForm += Form2_ButtonClickedToOtherForm;
        }

        //Button on Form2 has been clicked
        private void Form2_ButtonClickedToMainForm(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //change your Label Text here...
        }
```