# How to Call Label From form2 to Form1 c#

Tags: c#

i have form1 one textbox and one button(check purpose)
in form2 i have label1(name "Example")

code in check Button

```
Form f2 = new Form2();
 if (textbox.text != f2.label1)
 {
    MessageBox.Show("textbox Did Not Match to label")
 }
 else MessageBox.Show("textbox Match to label!")
```

Comment: could it be that you want:  if (textbox.Text != f2.label1.Text)

Comment: Add a public  IsLabelEqualTo() method to Form2?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change Label text on button click in a different form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37682138/change-label-text-on-button-click-in-a-different-form)

Comment: nope my problem is call label from form2 to form1

Answer (score 2):

Add this to Form2 Class:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string Label1Text => label1.Text;
}
```

Then:

```
Form f2 = new Form2();
if (textbox.text != f2.Label1Text)
{
    MessageBox.Show("textbox Did Not Match to label")
}
else MessageBox.Show("textbox Match to label!")
```

Or Create a **public method**:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public string GetLabel1Text()
    {
        return label1.Text;
    }
}
```

Then:

```
Form f2 = new Form2();
if (textbox.text != f2.GetLabel1Text())
{
    MessageBox.Show("textbox Did Not Match to label")
}
else MessageBox.Show("textbox Match to label!")
```

Comment: here is my code
`public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public string Label1Text;

        public Form2()
        {
            label1.Text = Label1Text;

            InitializeComponent();
        }`

what do you mean public string Label1Text => f2.label1.Text;?????

Comment: @DelMiranda any problem ?

Comment: @DelMiranda don't add it inside the constructor, but outside. follow the code in the answer. This is a shorthand for a method.

Comment: @DelMiranda i fixed it. It should be `public string Label1Text => label1.Text;` and not `public string Label1Text => f2.label1.Text;`

Comment: Form2
`public string GetLabel1Text()
        {
            return label1.Text;
        }`
Form1
`Form f2 = new Form2();
            if (textbox1.Text != f2.GetLabel1Text())`

error Error 1 'System.Windows.Forms.Form' does not contain a definition for 'GetLabel1Text' and no extension method 'GetLabel1Text' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.Form' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)